# App Settings - Azure App Service (Multiple environments)

Tags: azure, appsettings, azure-appservice

I am trying to set up connectivity from azure app service to azure sql db using managed identity (System assigned)

Here is the set up: Two azure app services one for app and one for api in one service plan. I have a SQL server in Azure with two azure sql db. The app services have their system assigned managed identity turned on. I have app settings for multiple environments in both the project (app and api).

```
appsettings.json
appsetings.Development.json
appsettings.Acceptance.json
appsettings.Production.json
```

When I explored Kudu after deploying my app to app service from yaml pipeline I see all the app settings files are available.

The configuration ->application setting in Azure app service just has the app insight instrumentation key which I add (IaC) in template while provisioning app service in Azure. In this situation:

If all the app settings file are pushed (as seen in Kudu), which app setting will be read? appsettings.json or any other environment specific? As I understand it should be appsettings.json. Will the best way to handle the app settings for different environments would be to only have appsettings.json and appsettings.development.json in solution/repo and while provisioning azure app service (IaC template), parameter files for different environments can have the required settings (stored as secrets in key vault and read)? Or any other way is better, easy, and secure? I am not sure how can I make use of secrets manager for multiple environment.

Comment: Based on the environment, `appsettings.json` file will be picked.If you have set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` based on that value configuration file will be picked.

Comment: If you want your Azuer App to pick any particular confuguration file, then in Azure App Service Configuration, set the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to the same.

Comment: Do you mean if I need it to pick appsettings.Test.json for Test web app, my Test web app service under Settings -> Configuration, should have an application setting with key ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and value Test?

Comment: Yes,you need to set the value in Azure App Service.

Comment: @Harshitha Please confirm my understanding and also how do you feel about the way I stated above with param file while deploying the respective app service rather than the values becoming a part of my repository? I mean from security perspective?

Comment: Will work on it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much, do let me know if any details required from my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253186/discussion-between-harshitha-and-lucky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned, reading of App settings will be based on the Environment.

- If we want the Azure App to pick any particular configuration file, then we need to set the key  `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`  with the specific value (`Development`/`Production`/`Acceptance`).

> When I explored Kudu after deploying my app to app service from yaml pipeline I see all the app settings files are available.

Yes, when we publish the  `Application`, all the available configuration   files are deployed to `Azure App Service`.

You can see the same for my application too.

***KUDU Console:***

[image]

- As you said you are deploying your app service from `yaml` pipeline, then the configurations which you have specified in the `yaml` file only will be used.
- Even though you see all the files in the KUDU Console, the configurations which are only specified in the `yaml` file be used in the App.
- AFAIK, the application setting which are only transformed in the `yaml` file are only read.
- You can find the option in `Azure App Service deploy`  Task in the `Pipeline`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- You can see the configurations of `yaml` in the `Azure App Service` => `Configuration` => `Application settings`.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmlvarsubs) for more information on XML Transformations.

> ```cs
> Will the best way to handle the app settings for different environments would be to only have appsettings.json and appsettings.development.json in solution/repo and while provisioning azure app service (IaC template), parameter files for different environments can have the required settings (stored as secrets in key vault and read)?
> ```

To Use `Azure Key Vault` for storing secrets we have an option in Aure Pipeline Task.

[image]

Thanks @[rahulpnath](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/handling-application-configuration/#environment-specific-configuration-values) for the clear explanation on `how configuration file works in different environment`.